# shopping cart and Session ID

Tags: php

I try to execute a shopping cart .In the beginning I save  the selected products in an array SESSION
while the customer order doesn't complete.
But,my work was imperfect because I don't use the session ID and I don't insert the selected products
to database,therefore I can't management the sessions.
Now, I want to improve my code to get an unique sessionID for each customer.
I see more examples in this issue and here I want to know which better to use:

```
//session_id($_GET['PHPSESSID']); session_start();
$session_id=session_id('PHPSESSID');
```

-OR-

```
session_start();
$sessionID = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
```

then,I will save the selected products to db width this  $session_id.

note that, I use a simple way to complete the customer order and store the selected
items to db, which is via customer email verification .after custmer verify his/her email
I want to go back him/her to a page that he/she can update his/her cart items or continue shopping.
here how to get the $session_id  to do that successfully.
please guide me in this issue.Thanks

Comment: wat about storing object ShoppingCart in $_SESSION array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both should return the same thing its just two different ways of referencing it. Although I would recommend against keying your users against session ids because the user can delete the cookie (which is where the id is stored) at anytime or it can expire and then you will have to create a whole new user which will cause you to lose all your records every time. I recommend keying your users against a primary key in the database.

Comment: Thanks cujomalainey,well,if I give a primary key for each session ,Is it true that to finish the customer order
after email verification I should send that key with the massage then when the user verify
his email the key would passed  back to my site to show the billing order.
another quesstion,
-can  this key be resulted from session_id('PHPSESSID') or automatic from db ?
-generally,Is it important to use session_id('PHPSESSID') here for another reasons?

Comment: Personally I never use PHPSESSID, i just feel there is to much risk around it. Usually i use my primary keys from my MySQL database. When you are doing the queries as long as the values are escaped they safe. Also MySQL can auto increment its fields so that takes care of having unique IDs. And yes they can be stored in a link in an email, some other people though prefer to use a token (like a md5 hash of the current time) to put in their email links for safety because its not guaranteed that the intended user will receive it but on your website it is because they just authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

Just store session id in cookie until (2 day for example) user return to site after email verification and then finish the order.